# Whati is the diffrence between bloginfo and template_directory_uri?

Tags: wordpress

I want to clear my concept that what is the difference between blog_info() and template_directory_uri() function? Please in details would be helpful!
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the [source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7.1/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L489), `get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' )` and `get_bloginfo( 'template_url' )` are simply wrappers for `get_template_directory_uri()`:

```
case 'template_directory':
case 'template_url':
    $output = get_template_directory_uri();
    break;
```

Comment: So `get_bloginfo('template_url')` and `get_template_directory_uri()` are functionally identical and *return* the value; meanwhile `bloginfo('template_url')` and `echo get_template_directory_uri()` are also functionally identical and *print* the value...

Answer (score 2):

IF you check with these links [blog_info](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo) and [template_directory_uri](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri) links you can clearly understand what is the difference between these two functions.

Anyway let me explain this for you

**template_directory_uri**

This function provides you the complete url to the theme directory you are currently using. Suppose if you are using **theme x** in your wordpress front-end, then when you call `template_directory_uri()` function it will return `http://yourdomainname.com/wp-content/themes/x`.  This essentialy means that this **function returns template directory URI for the current theme being used.**

**bloginfo**

What this function does is that it will return all the information associated with your site which are set in the admin general settings and admin user profile.  This function gives you information about the site url, admin email , site name, site description and lot of things. Most of these are available in the General Settings menu in the admin back-end. The **bloginfo** function accepts an input parameter. If you do not pass any input parameter by default it will show the Site title which is set in the admin back end. You can pass various other inputs like **description, url, charset, version etc**. These will give the info associated with them. **So what bloginfo gives us is, it will provide the information regarding the site.**

From bloginfo function we can get template_uri too, just do `bloginfo('template_url');`

If you prints out both these functions in your php page in wordpress theme, you can clearly found out what is the difference between these two functions. May be go to your index.php and just print out these two:

```
echo get_template_directory_uri();
bloginfo('name');
```

Hope this helps you